# How to pass realm object from Background thread to UiThread?

Tags: android, realm, android-annotations

How can i pass an realm object from @Background thread to @UiThread.

```
@UiThread
void setMessageCount(UserTripModel userTripModel) {
    tvMessageSent.setText(userTripModel.getMessageCount() + "");
}
```

this method is calling from @Background Thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying a RealmObject on a background thread, generally the right way to handle this update is to have a RealmChangeListener over a RealmResults that would contain this RealmObject.

Handle any background thread change via RealmChangeListener that observes for changes.

```
private Realm realm;
private RealmResults<UserTripModel> trips;
private RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<UserTripModel>> realmChangeListener = trips -> {
    // Set the trips to the adapter only when async query is loaded.
    // It will also be called for any future writes made to the Realm.

    // note that this is also where you could call `setMessageCount`.
    adapter.setData(trips);
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_realm_example);

    // This is the RecyclerView adapter
    adapter = new TripsAdapter();

    //This is the RecyclerView which will display the list of cities
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.cities_list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setOnItemClickListener(RecyclerViewExampleActivity.this);

    // Create a new instance of Realm
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    // Obtain the cities in the Realm with asynchronous query.
    trips = realm.where(UserTripModel.class).findAllAsync();

    // The RealmChangeListener will be called when the results are asynchronously loaded, and available for use.
    trips.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    trips.removeAllChangeListeners(); // Remove change listeners to prevent updating views not yet GCed.
    realm.close(); // Remember to close Realm when done.
}
```